# Accessing Amazon echo's alarm using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-echo, flask-ask

Currently building an app for work, and need to be able to access Alexa's in built alarm with python, so far i haven't found any obvious way of doing this.

I've hit a brick wall with how to approach this problem so it would be a big help if someone could point me in the right direction.